# How to work with two not interconnected Kafka brokers in one app?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-kafka

I need to implement simple gateway between two not interconnected Kafka brokers for one topic. I have one kerberized Kafka cluster in production and one broker with plain authentication for test purposes. Gateway should consume one topic from production cluster and produce messages from it to specified topic at test broker. How can I configure two different clients in single JAAS file with KafkaClient sections? Or it can be done programmatically?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't just use Mirror Maker?

Comment: I'm new to Kafka, so I didn't know that such tool as Mirror Maker exists. Thats exactly what I need. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to have one consumer pulling data from one cluster and one producer sending data to another cluster , producer and consumer may have different Kafka configs

Comment: It's obvious about one consumer and one producer with different properties. How to get different credentials for producer and consumer from single jaas file?